# Invert a two-dimentional binary array by the invert function,but this doesn't working,

Tags: javascript, arrays

Invert a two-dimentional  binary array by the invert function,but the function doesn't working after 'if(){...}'

```
        function invert(arr){

                   for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                   {
                           for(let j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++) 
                           {
                               //     or   arr[i][j]=~arr[i][j] ?;
                            if(arr[i][j]==0)   //start inverting the arr
                            {

                                    //all above are right,but the following operation seems not working
                                    arr[i][j]=1;
                            }
                            else{
                                    arr[i][j]=0; 
                            }
                           }
                   }

                   console.log(arr);  //print the array 
                    return arr;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Are these input and output in the screenshot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what's being shown in the console output, you don't have binary numbers in your array, you have strings made out of 0s and 1s -- which is not the same thing.

You could turn your array into a true 2D array of numeric 0s and 1s, as Pac0 suggested. Or, if you wanted to invert the strings in string form, and assuming the strings represent binary numbers of no more than 8 bits, you could do this:

```
arr.map(s => (~parseInt(s, 2) & 0xFF).toString(2))
```

Or, to handle this purely as string manipulation, matching whatever number of bits you want to use:

```
arr.map(s => s.replace(/[01]/g, b => b === '0' ? '1' : '0'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using your function with the wrong input.

You should define your array properly, as you defined it with words in your question title.

In the screen capture, you show some 1-dimensional array of strings `['100101', ...]` etc.. , not a 2-dimensional array of numbers `[[1,0,0,1,0,1], ...]` !

If you use your function with proper 2-dimensional arrays, where elements are indeed only 1s and 0s, then your function is working fine for me.

For instance :

```
 // suppose your function is already defined
 let testArr = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0]];
 invert(testArr);

 // now testArr is [[0,0,0],[0,0,1]];
```